# Can fungi transfer from a vintage camera to different camera/lens if put together?

Tags: vintage, fungus, dry-cabinet

I’ve bought a vintage film camera, and it has slight fungi inside the lens, but almost unnoticeable. I’m not sure if I can put it into the dry cabinet where my DSLR and lenses are. Can they transfer to other cameras and lenses in the same dry cabinet?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Why does fungus form in lenses, and how to get rid of it?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/14794)

Comment: Related: [If fungus affects my camera, is there risk of it moving to the lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/91198/15871)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fungus spores are already everywhere, so your DSLR and its lenses are already infected (and probably were since construction). But fungus needs high humidity to grow (which is why it's relatively rare to see it, except in *humid* climates).

So I think it very unlikely that your DSLR will start showing fungus growth from being stocked (dry) near an infected camera.